# Pinia and Vue 3 reactivity lost?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

I have a parent component called by main.js which contains a template and a v-if directive to show/hide a modal according to the value of a boolean (placeModalFlag), and a child component that has to show this modal. I created a Pinia store in main.js to facilitate communication between all these folks. Everything works fine from within the parent component (for test purposes) but the child can modify PlaceModalStore.isShown but not the boolean. I tried 'computed', 'ref', 'StoreToRefs' etc. Nothing seems to work...
In main.js, I have

```
const PlaceModalStore = usePlaceModalStore()
export { PlaceModalStore }
```

In the parent's script setup:

```
import { PlaceModalStore } from "./main.js"
const placeModalFlag = computed(() => PlaceModalStore.isShown )
```

In the parent's template

```
<teleport to="body">
        <transition name="fade">
          <PlaceTemplate v-if="placeModalFlag" @close-placeModal="PlaceModalStore.isShown = false" />
          <!-- "placeModalFlag = false"  -->
        </transition>
      </teleport>
```

In the child's script setup

```
import { PlaceModalStore } from '../main.js'
```

and finally in the child's script

```
export function checkPlaceName(eventPlace, eventCity, eventCounty, 
    eventRegion, eventCountry) {
    // some stuff here
        PlaceModalStore.isShown=true
    }
```

And the store is

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
export const usePlaceModalStore = defineStore('PlaceModalStore', {
  state: () => ({
    isShown: false,
    message: '',
    fullPlace: ''
    city: ''
    county: ''
    region: ''
    country: ''
    countryList: []
  }),
  actions: {
    setPlaceModalShow() {
      this.isShown = true
    },
    setPlaceModalHide() {
      this.isShown = false
    },
    setPlaceModalContent(message, fullPlace, city, county, region, country, countryList) {
      this.message = message
      this.fullPlace = fullPlace
      this.city = city
      this.county = county
      this.region = region
      this.country = country
      this.countryList = countryList
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Please share the store code

Comment: Code for the store added to my query

Comment: did you try out `PlaceModalStore.setPlaceModalShow()`?

Comment: Yes. PlaceModalStore.isShown is changed to true, but the modal does shows up.

Comment: Still no solution. The fact is ```const placeModalFlag = computed(() => { PlaceModalStore.isShown })``` does not fire from outside this component.

Comment: No one there to help? From within the parent component ```watch(() => PlaceModalStore.getShownFlag, (newVal) => {
      console.log('Propriété getShownFlag calculée mise à jour :', newVal)
    })``` shows the property was changed. But from the other component, ```watch()```is simply not fired in the parent component. Reactivity does not work in that case?